# Building a static library and application with OpenMP and GCC

Tags: c++, gcc, openmp, eigen

I have two projects which both are compiled using GCC:

1 - *my_static_lib_project* which uses Eigen and is build to generate a static lib `libmy_static_lib.a`
2 - *my_app_project* which is linked to `libmy_static_lib.a` to generate an executable *my_app*

I'm planning to use OpenMP to improve Eigen performance as described [here](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/TopicMultiThreading.html).

My question is:

- Should I compile only `libmy_static_lib.a` with flag `-fopenmp` or
- Should I flag only the build of `my_app` with `-fopenmp` or
- both builds `libmy_static_lib.a` and `my_app` need to be flagged with -fopenmp

Comment: The GNU OpenMP runtime is not really designed to be linked in statically. You may still try searching Stack Overflow thoroughly, since I recall this being discussed some time ago.

Comment: It's a bad idea in general to link OpenMP statically.  Regardless, of the final linkage, you should compile all source files that are linked together in the end with the -fopenmp flag, so that the compiler is aware of OpenMP for all compilation units.

Comment: @MichaelKlemm so to be clear the only project to flag with -fopenmp is the executable *my_app_project*, that is it?

Comment: `-fopenmp` enables two different things. For the compilation phase, it enables the recognition of OpenMP constructs and their transformations and also makes the path to `omp.h` known. For the link phase, it tells GCC to tell the linker (GNU `ld` on Linux) to link in the OpenMP runtime library and any other libraries it depends on. Note that GNU ld does not recognise `-fopenmp` and if you have a separate link step using it, you need to look into the GCC spec for what `-fopenmp` expands to when calling the linker. If you link using GCC, then pass `-fopenmp`.